# C execution stack - local variable allocation

Tags: c

I have a very basic question.
Lets take this snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void) {
    char *s = "StackOverflow";
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

int main(void) {
    foo();
}
```

In the process execution stack, main gets loaded on to the stack, then foo() gets called. 
Now, where is the memory for "StackOverflow" allocated?
Similarly where is the memroy for "%s\n" allocated when printf is called?

---

Consider the following code:

Now the other question I have is, considering the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x;
int abc = 100;

void foo(void) {
    char *s = "stackoverflow";
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

int main(void) {
    foo();
}
```

So, if I do objdump -s -j .bss a.out  , I should see uninitialized segment and if I do objdump -s -j .data a.out , I should see initialized segment (abc=100) rt? Is there anything wrong with this assumption?

I get the following outputs though:

test > objdump -s -j .bss a.out
a.out:     file format elf32-i386

test > objdump -s -j .data a.out

a.out:     file format elf32-i386

Contents of section .data:
 804954c 00000000 3c960408 00000000 64000000  ....<.......d...

What am I missing here?

thanks everyone again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"StackOverflow"` and `"%s\n"` string literals are put in `.rodata` (read only data ) section in most systems.

On UNIX, you can dump `.rodata` section using the objdump command:

```
$ gcc tst.c 
$ objdump -s -j .rodata a.out
```

As added by [@FatalError](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172428/fatalerror) in the comments, `"%s\n"` is not visible with objdump in the example as `gcc` optimizes a call to `printf("%s\n",str)` by replacing it by a call to `puts(str)`.

To see the `"%s\n"` string literal in the objdump output, you can compile your program with `gcc -fno-builtin`.

Comment: On linux (and similar) systems you can `objdump -s -j .rodata` on your binary to see it.  Also, if you use `gcc` you won't find "%s\n" because `gcc` optimizes that pattern into a call to `puts()`.

Comment: @FatalError I wrote the objdump command in the same time as your comment:) good point for `puts` I edit my answer to add it.

Answer (score 4):

The standard doesn't define where the storage for `"StackOverflow"` is located.

Often, it will be stored in the read-only text portion of your program; sometimes, it will be stored in the initialized data portion of your program.  Neither of these is the stack; neither of these is the 'heap' (in the sense of dynamically allocated memory managed by `malloc()` et al).  The same comments and issues arise for the format string.

Comment: As @ ouah and @FatalError suggested, I was able to see "Stackoverflow" and "%s" by doing objdump -s -j .rodata a.out.